# Using laravel, is it possible to populate a table with old values from back()->withInput()?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I need to use the old values sent back to the view on a failed submission to populate a table. Is this possible?

The normal inputs are populating fine. But I couldn't get access to the old value of the variable 'actions'.

My $request->input returns, amongst other things:

```
  "actions" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "{"action":"aaaaaa","what":"aaaaaaaaaaa","why":"aaaaa","when":"2021-11-04","who":["1"],"where":"aaaaaaaaaaaaa","how":"aaaaaaaaaa","action_users":["1"],"external_people":[]} ◀"
```

| Ação |    O que   | Por que   | Quando    | Quem (interno)    | Quem (externo) |  Onde    | Como  | Ações|

[The table I need to populate with the json data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsVt0.png)

{{old('actions', '')}} doesn't show any data, nor does @dump(old('actions', '').
I don't know if I didn't know how to search for, but I couldn't find anything on the topic.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: what about $request->get('actions') ... my guess is that actions is a reserved word

Comment: @TimLewis that actually makes sense, sorry.

Comment: @SamuelAialaFerreira I tried it and it still showed nothing. I don't think the request itself is being sent back